# What features of BlazeDS are not avaliable on CURRENT Google App Engine?

Tags: java, apache-flex, google-app-engine, blazeds, push-notification

So [here it is](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/web/will-it-play-in-app-engine) that BlazeDS will totally play on GAE

> BlazeDS Version: 3.2.0.3978 Status:
>   COMPATIBLE To workaround an
>   EMFException thrown by
>   flex.messaging.io.amf.AbstractAmfInput,
>   follow Martin Zoldano's workarounds at
>   http://martinzoldano.blogspot.com/2009/04/appengine-adobe-blazeds-fix.html.
>   You will need to enable sessions to
>   get BlazeDS working.

But I wonder does it mean that  messages from the server to the client, server push notifications from BlaseDS (I mean we connect to server from flex client but do not require data and server sends data to us when it wants), and BTW does any one know where to get a tutorial on doing that (Flex + BlazeDS)?

Are there any more features of Blaze v 3.2 that are under question?

Answer (score 1):

well i recently try a flex-blazeds app on google plattform and it doesnt works. I found a guide that [fix blazeds](http://martinzoldano.blogspot.com/2009/04/appengine-adobe-blazeds-fix.html) to run on gae, u should try it. For a basic tutorial of messaging-services in blazeds u should look a this  asotto.blogspot.com/ ,

Answer (score 1):

Messaging does not work, unless if you are lucky enough to have all the consumers/producers registered on the same machine (highly improbable when you have a decent traffic).

If you want to understand why, you need to read the developer guide, clustering sections. Basically the whole pub/sub graph+messages queues is kept distributed on the cluster, and the machines are using JGROUPS for communication.

Obviously, it will not work on GAE (the machines allocated by Google will don't know one of each other, and you can lose messages).

Answer (score 0):

With the official implementation of BlazeDS version 4 you have duplicated session problems, because of the GAE clustering mechanism.